# Достать ссылку на файл, который находится на хостинге timeweb, не понял, как это сделать?

Tags: php, telegram-bot

Вот видео, мне по нему нужно сделать телеграм бота именно на PHP
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mwVVE1tVHls
Застрял уже на второй минуте, т.к. толком не понял, где мне на моем хостинге взять ссылку на этот php файл

Захожу в файловый менеджер на тайм веб и в адресной строке эта ссылка: https://hosting.timeweb.ru/fileman
Мне что, дописать туда "/index.php"? Или как?
Извиняюсь за тупость

Comment: У вас подключено доменое имя к хостингу? если да то `domainname/pathtophp/filename.php` если нету то звоните хостеру может подскажет как по ip обратится если ip выделен

Comment: На видео у докладчика подключен свой домен `chastoedov.ru` он файл `index.php` положил в дирректорию `/project/meetup_telegram`